# typeError Cannot read property 'substr' of null

Tags: r

I have a dataframe "x" with words in the first column and numbers in the other columns, when trying to use the syntax:

`X$secondcolumn`

Get the error "typeError Cannot read property 'substr' of null", and the answer in R is:

`NULL`

I tried using the as.numeric function but didnt work.

`as.numeric(x)`

It says:

`Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

I need the values to be recognized as numbers to use for mathematical purposes but dont know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post (a part of) your dataframe ```X``` please?

Comment: try `unlist(x)` instead of `as.numeric(x)`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, when using the ```unlist(x)``` function removes all columns except the first one where all data is recorded now.

Comment: Restart R and try again. Also read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Hi, after restarting same thing happened, the values are now numeric but now I have just one column with more rows with all the values from the other rows in it.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example as mentioned in my earlier comment.